# Python: Bytes are written as strings

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, unicode, byte

```
# Text to Binary
message = "Hello"  # str
binary_message = message.encode('utf-8')
print(type(binary_message))  # bytes
f = open("bmsg", "wb")
f.write(binary_message)
f.close()
```

The above code writes the bytes as string. Here is how the file looks:

```
Hello
```

I thought It would write the binary representation of the string `Hello`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What is the "binary representation" of the string "Hello" that you expect? It's written 5 bytes whose values happen to be displayable as normal characters... what were you expecting?

Comment: I was expecting binary representation of `Hello` i.e 0s and 1s or hexadecimal? What am I missing?

Comment: you mean doing something like `f.write(binascii.hexlify(binary_message))` for instance?

Comment: Can you please explain why in this example characters are written as binary? https://pastebin.com/vMrfr9Yb

Comment: What am I missing?

Comment: I don't get where the confusion lays here... a byte can have one of 256 values... Some of those values happen to be easily viewable as certain characters... So if you write out the bytes `[104, 101, 108, 108, 111]`... then those values easily map to characters that are displayed as `hello`... so `h` is a byte with a value of 104... but it *displays* as `h`... in a text editor or similar... if you look at the file in a hex viewer/binary viewer then you'll see the *values* of the bytes rather than their representation

Comment: Text files are binary files.  They're just binary files that are read according to certain conventions.

Comment: @JonClements When I view the file written created by [this](https://pastebin.com/vMrfr9Yb) code it looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/k3N5tpB) ? Sure there are printable characters but it is not in display? Why ?

Comment: It looks like you're opening it in Sublime Text? If so - if there's null bytes (I think) it defaults to a hex view... go to File->Reopen with Encoding->UTF8 and you'll get displayable characters and glyphs for characters it can't display...

Comment: That's because your text editor reads the file and does not recognize encoding of the bytes, so it bails out and shows it in hex.

Comment: @JonClements that was case.